# Redefining built-in ruby function

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to redefine a built-in ruby function for the whole application?

Example :

I want a new definitions for puts:

```
def puts
  return nil
end
```

I know that redefining puts is stupid, but this is just an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is; are you having a specific issue?

Comment: You just have to make sure to re-open the `class` or `module` that contains the method/function that you want to redefine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible:

```
module Kernel
  def puts(*)
    42
  end
end

puts "does it work?"
#=> 42
```

The question is: Does it make sense? :)

Answer (score 2):

Tessi shows you a strict override. Instead you can also do a wrapping:

```
module Kernel
  alias :real_puts :puts

  def puts *args
      real_puts args
      42
  end
end


puts puts "Hello World", "Bye"
#Hello world
#Bye
#42
```